# How to change this list tuple into list only in Python?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list like this:

```
  [[(u'hello@hello.com',)], [(u'hello@hello.com',)]]
```

I want to convert this into:

```
[['hello@hello.com'], ['hello@hello.com']]
```

How can I do this?

Another example:
Input: `[[(u'hello',), (u'hello',)], [(u'hello',)]]` 
Should return `[['hello@hello.com', 'hello@hello.com'], ['hello@hello.com']]`

Comment: Why I downvoted this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149138/133242

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
test = [[(u'hello',), (u'hello',)], [(u'hello',)]]
for i, part_i in enumerate(test):
    for j, part_j in enumerate(part_i):
        test[i][j] = str(part_j[0])
```

Or, if you prefer the one-line version:

```
test = [[(u'hello',), (u'hello',)], [(u'hello',)]]
result = [[str(j[0]) for j in i] for i in test]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new = [[j[0].encode('utf-8') for j in i] for i in old]
```

UTF-8 is just an example, you should really make sure you get the encoding right.

Comment: Still a unicode? How to remove?

Comment: Doesn't work with: [[(u'hello',), (u'hello',)], [(u'hello',)]] Should return [['hello@hello.com', hello@hello.com], ['hello@hello.com']]